# How to set download file name html2pdf.js on blob url

Tags: naming, html2pdf, bloburls

I am using [html2pdf.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js)

I should show **preview** before my customer will download files.

The way of '**dataurlnewwindow**' can show preview, but **download button is not working**.

So i change **bloburl** output, and download button is working.

But when i clicked download, **i wanna set the download filename**.

As you can see below, i cant set the download file name.
[image]

Does anyone knows to handle it?

This is my html2pdf.js code i used.

```
const opt = { margin: 10, filename, html2canvas: { width: 800, useCORS: true } };
html2pdf().set(opt).from(html).output('bloburl').then(r => { window.open(r) })
```

Even you guys know to support preview and download with name, plz tell me. i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting the filename at `<a>` tag in `download` property.

```
html2pdf().from(html)
          .set(opt)
          .toPdf()
          .get('pdf')
          .then((pdf) => downloadPdf(pdf, options));

const downloadPdf = (pdf, opt) => {
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.target = '_blank';
    link.href = pdf.output('bloburl');
    link.download = 'myFileName.pdf';
    link.click();
    link.remove();
}
```

This will open PDF in a new tab page, because of `target=_blank` and download it right after the `click()` event on `<a>` tag element.

Answer (score 0):

only set filename in .save('your file name.pdf') in code. just it
const e
html2pdf(document.getElementById('element')).save(`${order_number.innerHTML}.pdf`)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).